# Grabbing CreationDate of Defect Objects

Tags: date, object, parent, rally, defects

How can I find the CreationDate of a Defect Object in rally?

I have an array of defects objects, and I am able to find all the attributes of defects by doing the following in a loop:

```
project = defects[i].Project.Name;
environment = defects[i].Environment;
```

etc for all the other attributes I want, but CreationDate doesnt work...

I tried

```
creationDate = defects[i].PersistableObject.CreationDate;
creationDate = defects[i].CreationDate;
```

But it returns 'undefined'

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Which SDK toolkit are you using? Javascript/SDK1 or SDK2? Or a different language?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include CreationDate in the fetch for your request?  If so you should be able to access it on each result as you did above:

```
creationDate = defects[i].CreationDate;
```

Comment: I did not have CreationDate in my fetch request, I'm sure that would have worked. I ended up creating a separate query that filtered for CreationDate before returning the results. Basically the same thing, but I am having the query do the work instead of sorting through it after the results are returned.

Thanks for the help!